# Same folder, different size

Tags: directory

I am trying to move a big folder (15gb) from a NTFS external HDD to my laptop running UBUNTU 11.10. In order to be sure that i was copying the correct folder, i double checked the size of the relevant folder first connecting the HDD to a windows7 machine, showing 15gb / 7675 files, then performing the same task after connecting the HDD to my laptop. To my surprise, im the latter case, the size goes up to 16.2gb with 0ver 7800 files.

Could you kindly explain to me the reason for this? Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Is it filesystem related?

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm guessing you have about 125 folders? That would explain the differing number of files.
2. The difference in size can be caused by a number of factors, I guess Windows reported GiB's => 15GB*1024*1024*1024 = 16,106,127,360  and Linux is reporting in GB's => 16,2GB * 1000,000,000 = 16,200,000,000. The difference between 16.1 and 16.2 can easily be a rounding error in my example.

You can check #1 from the commandline:

```
$ find your_folder -type f | wc -l
$ find your_folder -type d | wc -l
```

The first line will report the number of files.
The second line will report the number of directories.

You can check #2 from the commandline:

```
$ du -sh your_folder
$ du -s -si your_folder
```

The first option will report in GiB, the second in GB.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Answer (score 1):

check the differences using the following command

```
diff /directory/path/of/ntfs/folder   /directory/path/of/ubuntu/folder
```